# Json format correctly in my input

Tags: php, jquery, sql, json

I'm able to print a json into two inputs after an autocomplete. The problem is that they show all the json. Exemple:

`[{"cliName":"GRC Att: S. Gosselin","proDescription":"Entretien GRC"}]`

But I only want to keep the name : `GRC Att: S. Gosselin` for the first input and the second I need to keep : `entretien GRC`

Here my code for autocomplete.php :

```
    <!-- numéro de projet du dimanche -->
            <td>

                <span id="numpro" >

    <form method="post" action="">
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name"onkeypress="return handleEnter(event, this, 'task');"/>
      </form>


                </span>

            </td>

</script>
    <!-- client du dimanche -->
            <td>
                <span id="proclient">

                    <input type="text" name="client1" size="12" disabled id ="client1" class "client" >


                </span>
            </td>

    <!-- description du projet de dimanche -->
            <td>
                <span id="prodesc">
                    <input type="text" name="desc1" size="30" disabled id ="desc1" class "desc">
                </span>
            </td>
```

Here my code for index.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $("#name").autocomplete({
                        source:'getautocomplete.php',
                        minLength:1
                    });
                });


                    function handleEnter(e, obj, field){
                    if (e.keyCode == 13 || e.which == 13){

                        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                          {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                          }
                        else
                          {// code for IE6, IE5
                          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                          }
                        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
                          {
                          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                            {
                            var json = xmlhttp.responseText;

                            alert(json);
                            //document.getElementById("desc1").value=window.atob(xmlhttp.responseText);
                            //document.getElementById("client1").value=window.atob(xmlhttp.responseText1);

            $("#client1").val(json);
                $("#desc1").val(json);



                            }
                          }
                        xmlhttp.open("GET","completeclient.php?q="+obj.value,true);

                        xmlhttp.send();



                    }

                    //Enter was pressed, handle it here


                    }


        </script>
```

And finaly where I take my information completeclient.php

```
<?php

//connect to db


$mysqli  = new mysqli($host_name,$user_name,$pass_word, $database_name);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
//mysqli_select_db($database_name, $con);


$var="";
 $var=$_GET["q"];
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("select cliName,proDescription from projets,clients where proNum like '%$var%' AND proCliID = cliID  ");
 //$json=array();

$stmt->execute();


$res = $stmt->get_result();
$row = $res->fetch_assoc();

    $json[]=array(
               'cliName'=> $row['cliName'],
               'proDescription'=>$row['proDescription']
                   );


//$message = ($row['cliName']);
// echo (base64_encode($message));
 echo json_encode($json);
 //echo $result;





//$datas = array('client' => $row['cliName'], 'description' => $row['proDescription']);
//json_encode($datas);



?>
```

Thankk for help !

Comment: your description about what you want is really ambiguous ...

Comment: Here better description : I have 3 input. In my input1 I have an autocomplete function exemple I type 07-... It complete 07-0138. When I press enter. He give me in my Input 2 and input3 this for each : [{"cliName":"GRC Att: S. Gosselin","proDescription":"Entretien GRC"}] . I want to split the information in my inpu2 I only want my clientname : "GRC Att: S. Gosselin" and in my input 3 i only want description : Entretien GRC . How Do I split this?

Comment: @TheBaconManWithouBacon it is still not clear, I suggest you to show what the desired JSON should look like.

Comment: My Json look like this :  [{"cliName":"GRC Att: S. Gosselin","proDescription":"Entretien GRC"}] . I want to keep the first part in  input 2 : GRC Att: S. Gosselin. And finaly I want to keep this part Entretien GRC in my input 3. My input 2 name is : client1 and my input 3 is desc1 as you can see in my code.

Comment: @TheBaconManWithouBacon - you can use a temp array `$temp_array = $json` then you could use `unset($temp_array['cliName'])` for input 3 and `unset($temp_array['proDescription'])` for input 2. Then you could use `echo json_encode($temp_array);`.

Comment: Where do I put it? cause this is my javascript function I fill my data in this `code       var json = xmlhttp.responseText;
    $temp_array = $json
       alert(json);
       //document.getElementById("desc1").value=window.atob(xmlhttp.responseText);
       //document.getElementById("client1").value=window.atob(xmlhttp.responseText1);
    
   $("#client1").val(unset($temp_array['cliName']));

   $("#desc1").val(json);
  `

Comment: @TheBaconManWithouBacon - in Javascript use `delete` instead of `unset` in php. e.g. `delete tempArrayInJS["cliName"];`

Comment: when I'm doing this they return me True in my input `code var $json = xmlhttp.responseText;
       $tempArray = $json;
       alert($json);
       $("#client1").val(delete $tempArray["cliName"]);`.

Comment: @TheBaconManWithouBacon you are mixing php and jquery

Comment: @TheBaconManWithouBacon - no you shouldn't have used `delete` inside `val()`. first create a new array `tempArrayInJS = json;` without any `$`. then delete a key using `delete tempArrayInJS["cliName"];`. Finally you can use `$("#client1").val(tempArrayInJS);`

Comment: this is the  `code var json = xmlhttp.responseText;
       tempArrayInJS = json;
       alert(json);
      delete tempArrayInJS["cliName"] ;
      $("#client1").val(tempArrayInJS); ` and this is the input2 give me : [{"cliName":"GRC Att: S. Gosselin","proDescription":"Entretien GRC"}. Like the same thing I did in my exemple of code. I just want keep GRC Att: S. Gosselin in my input 2 now all of my json.

Comment: Same :{"cliName":"GRC Att: S. Gosselin","proDescription":"Entretien GRC"}.

Comment: @TheBaconManWithouBacon - Please notice that you alerted `json` every time. you should `alert(tempArrayInJS);`. plz also ignore my last comment.

Comment: `var json = xmlhttp.responseText;`
`var tempArrayInJS = json;` 
`alert(tempArrayInJS);`
`delete tempArrayInJS["cliName"] ; ` `$("#client1").val(tempArrayInJS);`

Comment: they print again : [{"cliName":"GRC Att: S. Gosselin","proDescription":"Entretien GRC"}. With your code `code   var json = xmlhttp.responseText;
       var tempArrayInJS = json;
       alert(tempArrayInJS); 
      delete tempArrayInJS["cliName"] ; 
      $("#client1").val(tempArrayInJS);`

Comment: Here is the answer if someone want to know : 
    $("#client1").val( tempArrayInJS[0]['cliName']); and my mistake was my input too 
    <!-- BEFORE <input type="text" name="client1" size="12" disabled id ="client1" class "client" > -->
     <input type="text" name="client1" class = "client" size="12" id ="client1" disabled />